# How to move matrix from one side of equation to the other?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am trying to use an inversed matrix to solve system of equations, however, I have encountered a problem that is making me confused.

---

**General Step for using an inversed matrix to solve system of equations:**

$AX=B$ (Step 1)

$A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}B$ (Step 2)

$X=A^{-1}B$ (Step 3)

---

Specifically, for step 2, I know the fact that matrix multiplication is not commutative (So $A^{-1}B ≠ BA^{-1}$ ). That is why I would like to ask:

**Why, when we multiply $A^{-1}$ on the left of equation, the right side is $A^{-1}B$ but not $BA^{-1}$ ?**

**And for future, how can I know the position of the inverse matrix, when I multiply it by both side?**

Ex:
For AB=ED,

Should $A^{-1}AB=EDA^{-1}$?

Or $A^{-1}AB=EA^{-1}D$?

Or $A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}ED$?

Comment: You're left multiplying $A^{-1}$ on both sides of the equation. It's invalid to say $AX=B\Rightarrow A^{-1}X=BA^{-1}$ because then you're doing a different operation to both sides of the equation.

Comment: So in the case of $A^{-1}AB$ should equal to $A^{-1}ED$ ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!